# migrating from D3.js v6 to v7 in typescript + node environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to make d3 **v7** work in `Typescript + Node` environment. The previous code on d3 v6 was working fine with these configurations:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",  
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

and there was **NO** `"type": "module"` in `package.json` file.

---

What I've tried (step-by-step):

1. Updated d3 to v7 and restarted the app; Error:

```js
/app/dist/controllers/d3-node.js:4
const d3_1 = require("d3");
             ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /app/node_modules/d3/src/index.js from /app/dist/controllers/d3-node.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /app/dist/controllers/d3-node.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

which was expected due to [d3 v7 changes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md).

2. knowing that I need to **make Typescript compiler generate `import` statements instead of `require`**, I changed the `tsconfig.json` to:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",  
    "module": "ES2020", /* <------------- */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  }
}
```

which results in this error (as expected):

```js
import app from '../app.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

3. To solve the previous error, I added `"type": "module"` to `package.json`, hoping this would (finally!) solve the issue.

Basically the change caused all import statements to break; so as an example, this import:

```js
import app from '../app'
```

results in:

```js
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/app/dist/app' imported from /app/dist/bin/www.js
```

After finding this [#13422 issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422) on GitHub, I know that **I should add `.js` to the end of import statements to make it work**.

But the project has dozens of import statements and BTW, as discussed in the issue, it *doesn't feels right* to have all those `.js` extensions, even though we're writing Typescript.

Is there any other way to make it work without adding the `.js` to all the import statements?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. That's why I try to avoid ESModules in TypeScript projects. The module systems just don't play along well (yet?).